# On Azure Repos, how to get master branch to publish to production environment, and other branches to preview environments, on Azure Static Web App

Tags: azure, azure-devops, pipeline, azure-repos, azure-static-web-app

I've been struggling with this for days now:

I have an Angular web app with the code on an Azure Repo git. I've created an Azure Static Web App to host it in, which automatically created a pipeline on Azure Repo to build and deploy the master branch. However, what I'd like to do is use preview environments. Specifically, I'd like it that when I push a commit to the dev branch, the branch gets built and deployed to a dev preview environment on Static Web App. Similarly, if I push a commit to the staging branch, then the pipeline should build and deploy the branch to a staging preview environment on Static Web App. And finally, if I push a commit to the master branch, that branch should be built and published to the production environment on Static Web App.

Now, I've amended the auto-generated pipeline to the following:

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - master

trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - dev
      - staging
      - master

jobs:
  - job: build_and_deploy_job_development
    displayName: Build and Deploy Development
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/dev'))
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    variables:
      - group: Azure-Static-Web-Apps-red-pebble-0152f4f03-variable-group
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        submodules: true
      - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
        inputs:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_RED_PEBBLE_0152F4F03)
          app_location: "/" 
          api_location: "" 
          output_location: "dist/propworx-portal"
          action: "preview"
          target_branch: "dev"
          azure_static_web_apps_environment: "Development"
          
  - job: build_and_deploy_job_staging
    displayName: Build and Deploy Staging
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/staging'))
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    variables:
      - group: Azure-Static-Web-Apps-red-pebble-0152f4f03-variable-group
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        submodules: true
      - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
        inputs:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_RED_PEBBLE_0152F4F03)
          app_location: "/" 
          api_location: "" 
          output_location: "dist/propworx-portal"
          action: "preview"
          target_branch: "staging"
          azure_static_web_apps_environment: "Staging"
          
  - job: build_and_deploy_job_production
    displayName: Build and Deploy Production
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master'))
    pool:
      vmImage: ubuntu-latest
    variables:
      - group: Azure-Static-Web-Apps-red-pebble-0152f4f03-variable-group
    steps:
      - checkout: self
        submodules: true
      - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
        inputs:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_RED_PEBBLE_0152F4F03)
          app_location: "/" 
          api_location: "" 
          output_location: "dist/propworx-portal"
          action: "upload"
          azure_static_web_apps_environment: "Production"
```

However, if I push to the dev branch, for example, the pipeline runs (only the "build_and_deploy_job_development" job, not the other two), and when it completes, it says:

```
Visit your site at: https://red-pebble-0152f4f03.2.azurestaticapps.net
```

Now, that is the URL of the production environment. Looks like it published the branch to the production environment and not to a preview environment?

Basically, I'd like the dev and staging branches to be on preview environments, at a URL such as:

> https://red-pebble-0152f4f03.2-dev.azurestaticapps.net
> and
> https://red-pebble-0152f4f03.2-staging.azurestaticapps.net

and the production branch to be on the production environment at the main URL:

> https://red-pebble-0152f4f03.2.azurestaticapps.net

On Azure Portal, if I go to the Static Web App, and then to the Environments tab, I only see a production environment, and no preview environments. I cannot create a new preview environment as there is no "Add" button, only a "Refresh" and "Delete" button. I'm not sure if I need to create the Environments in Azure DevOps first? I'm a bit lost. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

**I have tried to repro the same using the below steps and got the positive output after doing few modifications in pipeline code.**

When I create Azure static webapp, it has created a pipeline code automatically as below.

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master

jobs:
- job: build_and_deploy_job
  displayName: Build and Deploy Job
  condition: or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'),or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'),eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI')))
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  variables:
  - group: Azure-Static-Web-Apps-orange-moss-006b7d710-variable-group
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_ORANGE_MOSS_006B7D710)
###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
# For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
      app_location: "/" # App source code path
      api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
      output_location: "dist/ang-swa" # Built app content directory - optional
###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######
```

I have added variables and conditions to make it work as per the requirements.

```
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

variables:
  isMain: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')]
  isDev: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/dev')]

pr:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - master
      - dev
      - staging

jobs:
- job: build_and_deploy_job_prod
  displayName: Build and Deploy Job
  condition: and( eq(variables.isMain, true), or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'),or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'),eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'))))
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  variables:
  - group: Azure-Static-Web-Apps-orange-moss-006b7d710-variable-group
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_ORANGE_MOSS_006B7D710)
###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
# For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
      app_location: "/" # App source code path
      api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
      output_location: "dist/ang-swa" # Built app content directory - optional
###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######

- job: build_and_deploy_job_dev
  displayName: Build and Deploy Job Dev
  condition: and( eq(variables.isDev, true), or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'),or(eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'),eq(variables['Build.Reason'], 'IndividualCI'))))
  pool:
    vmImage: ubuntu-latest
  variables:
  - group: Azure-Static-Web-Apps-orange-moss-006b7d710-variable-group
  steps:
  - checkout: self
    submodules: true
  - task: AzureStaticWebApp@0
    inputs:
      azure_static_web_apps_api_token: $(AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_ORANGE_MOSS_006B7D710)
###### Repository/Build Configurations - These values can be configured to match your app requirements. ######
# For more information regarding Static Web App workflow configurations, please visit: https://aka.ms/swaworkflowconfig
      app_location: "/" # App source code path
      api_location: "" # Api source code path - optional
      output_location: "dist/ang-swa" # Built app content directory - optional
###### End of Repository/Build Configurations ######
      deployment_environment: 'Development'
```

After adding variables and modifying the conditions at the stage level, it is working as expected. Please find the below screenshot.

[image]