# How can i access my react VITE ENV variables in production of an azure static web app?

Tags: reactjs, azure, environment-variables, pipeline, vite

locally i use a .env file and do the following:

```
const value = import.meta.env.VITE_VALUETOGET
console.log("value", value )
```

When i go to production however i use the azure portal configuration app settings and added VITE_VALUETOGET with the value, this doesn't work because i get undefined if i try to log it.

I also tried to use pipeline to deploy the app and export the values from azure vault before i deploy it but nothing seems to work, process.env neither.

I also tried vite.config.js:

```
export default defineConfig({
  mode: 'production',
  plugins: [
    react(),

    // Add the replace plugin to inject environment variables
    replace({
      'import.meta.env.VITE_VALUETOGET': JSON.stringify(process.env.VITE_VALUETOGET)
    }),
  ],
});
```

Comment: Refer to this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/352579/azure-web-app-service-react-the-environment-variab)

Comment: Refer this for production configuration in static web [app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/preview-environments) [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/build-configuration) and [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75674422/on-azure-repos-how-to-get-master-branch-to-publish-to-production-environment-a)

Answer (score 1):

> Access [env](https://dev.to/orama254/how-to-use-environment-variables-in-vite-react-template-example-34ff) variables from Azure Static Web App · [Discussion](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/13443) [Variables](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#using-the-vars-context-to-access-configuration-variable-values).
> VITE ENV variables in the production of an Azure static web app.Used this reference for Building for [Production](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html)

```js
   const value = import.meta.env.VITE_VALUETOGET  
     console.log('process.env', process.env);
```

- Refer this Env Variables and [Modes](https://vitejs.dev/guide/env-and-mode.html)

```json
   {  
     "NODE_ENV": "production",  
     "PUBLIC_URL": "",  
     "FAST_REFRESH": true  
   }
```

[image]

[image]

- Use Environment Variables in Vite.The **startup command** contains `npx serve -l 8080 .`
- For other details refer this  How to load [environment](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/352579/azure-web-app-service-react-the-environment-variab) variables from .env file using [Vite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70709987/how-to-load-environment-variables-from-env-file-using-vite).